# Как сделать чтобы значение тега `<p>` вставлялось в iframe default-sum=**1125** при нажатии на btn?

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать чтобы значение тега `<p>` вставлялось в iframe default-sum=**1125** при нажатии на btn ?

```
<div class="portfolio-info-price">
    <p>1125 руб. </p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Купить</a>
</div>


<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" width="450" height="198"
        src="https://money.yandex.ru/embed/shop.xml?account=4100000000000&quickpay=shop&payment-type-choice=off&writer=seller&targets=Page Order&targets-hint=&default-sum=**1125**&button-text=02&successURL="></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Создавайте iframe налету.

```
 var iframeSrc = tmplSrc + '&default-sum=' + value,
     iframeId = 'myFrame' + count++;
 $('<iframe />', {'id': iframeId, 'src': iframeSrc}).appendTo('body');
 var iframe = $('#' + iframeId).get(0);
```